# How does a stellar node know that node its communicating with is definitively in or outside its quorum group?

Tags: consensus, scp, nodes

In order for SCP to function properly, a given node has to know that a quorum related message originated from a node in its quorum set.

How does this node know for a fact that the message originated from a quorum-set-included-node, instead of a random node that may be trying to impersonate a node in the quorum set? What if an attacker tried to IP spoof for example?

Answer (score 1):

> The protocol consists of exchanging digitally-signed messages bound to nodes' quorum slices.

( https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-mazieres-dinrg-scp/ )

The trusted nodeIds that you put in your quorum set `VALIDATORS` configuration are in fact public keys of the secret `NODE_SEED`s from the opposing nodes.